# how to get exception message in C#

Tags: .net, exception

when in vs debug mode,we usually got an exception tip like this :[image] ,
I want to getthe message "TestConsole.Program.Test.Name.get 返回 null",but in my way (ex.Message or ex.StackTrace),i got the message "System.NullReferenceException:“Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”".
how to do? thanks

ex.Message, or ex.StackTrace or any other

Comment: If you have `try-catch` and set a breakpoint in the `catch` you will be able to look at the `Exception` and see all of its properties - this way you can see which one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch. Put your execution code into try part.

```cs
try
{

// your code goes here

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // here you can process your exception, like write message, or use stacktrace, etc..
    System.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```